# Regular expression to skip some specific characters

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I am trying to clean the string such that it does not have any punctuation or number, it must only have a-z and A-Z.
For example,given String is:

```
"coMPuter scien_tist-s are,,,  the  rock__stars of tomorrow_ <cool>  ????"
```

Required output is :

```
['computer', 'scientists', 'are', 'the', 'rockstars', 'of', 'tomorrow']
```

My solution is

```
re.findall(r"([A-Za-z]+)" ,string)
```

My output is

```
['coMPuter', 'scien', 'tist', 's', 'are', 'the', 'rock', 'stars', 'of', 'tomorrow', 'cool']
```

Comment: Your best solution is o use a simple replace to remove all characters that aren't a-z and space. `[^A-Za-z ]+` (you can substitute `\s` in the place of the space behind the closing bracket, and then perform a split on the string with space as a delimiter. In the regex, you can

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?.

Comment: @cfqueryparam thanks i go what you are saying   re.sub( r'([^a-zA-Z\s]+)', '', s).split()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expression:

(Convert the string into lower case if you want all lower-cased words), Split words, then filter out word that starts with alphabet:

```
>>> s = "coMPuter scien_tist-s are,,,  the  rock__stars of tomorrow_ <cool>  ????"
>>> [filter(str.isalpha, word) for word in s.lower().split() if word[0].isalpha()]
['computer', 'scientists', 'are', 'the', 'rockstars', 'of', 'tomorrow']
```

In Python 3.x, `filter(str.isalpha, word)` should be replaced with `''.join(filter(str.isalpha, word))`, because in Python 3.x, `filter` returns a filter object.

Comment: Thanks it works for me .... can you please tell me that regular expression is more time efficient or this loop method ?

Comment: @RajaHammadFarooq, No regular expression answer was given, so I can't compare.

Answer (score 3):

With the recommendation of all of the people who answered I got the correct solution that i really wants , Thanks to every one...

```
s = "coMPuter scien_tist-s are,,,  the  rock__stars of tomorrow_ <cool>  ????"    
cleaned = re.sub(r'(<.*>|[^a-zA-Z\s]+)', '', s).split()
print cleaned
```

Comment: What if `cool` is surrounded by `"`? `... tomorrow_ "cool"` should it be included?

Answer (score 1):

using `re`, although I'm not sure this is what you want because you said you didn't want "cool" leftover.

```
import re

s = "coMPuter scien_tist-s are,,,  the  rock__stars of tomorrow_ <cool>  ????"

REGEX = r'([^a-zA-Z\s]+)'

cleaned = re.sub(REGEX, '', s).split()
# ['coMPuter', 'scientists', 'are', 'the', 'rockstars', 'of', 'tomorrow', 'cool']
```

**EDIT**

```
WORD_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?!<?\S+>)(?=\w)(\S+)')
CLEAN_REGEX = re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z])')

def cleaned(match_obj):
    return re.sub(CLEAN_REGEX, '', match_obj.group(1)).lower()

[cleaned(x) for x in re.finditer(WORD_REGEX, s)]
# ['computer', 'scientists', 'are', 'the', 'rockstars', 'of', 'tomorrow']
```

`WORD_REGEX` uses a positive lookahead for any word characters and a negative lookahead for <...>. Whatever non-whitespace that makes it past the lookaheads is grouped:

```
(?!<?\S+>) # negative lookahead
(?=\w) # positive lookahead
(\S+) #group non-whitespace
```

`cleaned` takes the match groups and removes any non-word characters with `CLEAN_REGEX`

Comment: OP wants `['computer', 'scientists', 'are', 'the', 'rockstars', 'of', 'tomorrow']`.

Comment: yes it also a very good approach, i also want to skip  "<cool> " any text within <> brackets, what should i do ??